# FileDialog with input to save file

Tags: qml, qfiledialog

I have one FileDialog to save one file. This FileDialog have "folder" property and "nameFilter". How I can add one box to input the name of the file that user want to save? Any other component to achieve that? At least, Can I change the name of the buttons in this component?

Comment: Show a [mcve], otherwise it difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Did you read the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#details)? It says - _The implementation of FileDialog will be a platform file dialog if possible. If that isn't possible, then it will try to instantiate a QFileDialog. If that also isn't possible, then it will fall back to a QML implementation, DefaultFileDialog.qml_. So in general you can't change the dialog appearence but only if not system dialog nor `QFileDialog` supported. On the other hand you can take `DefaultFileDialog.qml` as example and construct your own dialog to use in your applicaton.